# Accidentally moved the home Directory to another folder

Tags: directory, home-directory

I was trying to move a folder "Foxit Reader" which was located in `/opt`  to the home Directory. I searched on how to do that and they told me to do this :

```
sudo su 
cd /opt
mv -t Foxit\ Reader/ /home
```

But apparently what it did was moving all the home to inside the foxit reader folder.
and now I can't open anything, how can I fix this?

Comment: Your `/opt` or `/` on the same partition as your *previous* `/home`?

Comment: Did you try to do the reverse operation ? If you are in the same directoy which you executed the above commands, try `sudo mv Foxit\ Reader/home/* /home` ? What did you mean by _Cant open anything_ what did you try to open ? Be careful when trying these commands. I hope you didnt restart the machine

Comment: all the contents inside home folder were transferred to /opt/Foxitreader

Comment: @eyadkht good you got it fixed but for next time: please carefully read what a command does! This one is easy to fix but I know several that can not be reversed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "-t" means that "Foxit\ Reader/" is the target to move the files to. And the next argument is assumed to be the source from where to move it from.

From the manual:

```
 -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

You can fix this by doing:

```
sudo su 
cd /opt/"Foxit Reader"/
ls -l *
```

and visually confirm you see a list of users (that are directories) (not Desktop, Pictures etc) and not files. Then you can do ...

```
mv * /home/
```